# How to pipe a tcl command within bash or zsh shell?

Tags: shell, tcl, pipe

Basically what I am trying to do is to pipe a `tcl` command within a `zsh` shell. Most common piping are `grep`, `awk` and `sed` for text manipulation.

With `perl` and `ruby` there is the `-e` option which allows to execute statements directly from the shell without writing a script on a file.

Is it possible to achieve the same thing in `tcl`?

Thank you.

Comment: Not exactly, but expect has `-e`.

Comment: On my system expect works with the `-c` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tclsh` does not have anything like `-e`; it's a very simple wrapper round the Tcl library.

You can *simulate* with a script like this:

```
apply {{} {
    global argv0 argv argc
    if {[lindex $argv 0] eq "-e"} {
        set script [lindex $argv 1]
        set argv [lrange $argv 2 end]
        incr argc -2
        uplevel #0 $script
    } else {
        set argv0 [lindex $argv 0]
        set argv [lrange $argv 1 end]
        incr argc -1
        uplevel #0 [list source $argv0]
    }
}}
```

If you make a script with that in called `tclhelper.tcl` and define a shell alias:

```
alias tcl='tclsh tclhelper.tcl'
```

Then you'll be able to do:

```
tcl -e "puts [info patchlevel]"
```

and see things work.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by piping your tcl one liner to `tclsh` with `|`, ex:

```
echo 'puts "do_something"' | tclsh
```